# Why isn't 'to' a required parameter in ethereum transaction?

Tags: transactions

In "Mastering Ethereum" I have read that "It is a good practice to always specify 'to' parameter' so that we decrease risk of sending our ether to 0x0 address.
If it is known that such scenario may occur then why isn't this field somehow treated as required instead of being the optional one?

Answer (score 0):

Because using To = `nil` is the way you deploy contract on the blockchain. The address of the new contract will be returned at the Receipt. This is why `to` parameter can be omitted when you send a transaction. Obviously you need to include executable code in the `Data` field if you are using `to` = `nil`

the phrase "it is a good practice to specify "to" parameter" is nonsense. If you specify `to` parameter incorrectly you will lose money.